# How can I schedule supervisord to start and stop on regular intervals(for example to start at everyday 1:00 AM UTC and stop at 6AM UTC)

Tags: amazon-web-services, process, supervisord

I did configured supervisor to process the jobs from AWS SQS queue(using laravel dispatch to AWS SQS), I have below command in /etc/supervisor.conf and I want to run this command on regular intervals:

command=sudo php /home/../artisan queue:work sqs --daemon --sleep=300

Is it possible? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using Unix you need [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), which is built into every Unix OS and has been for decades.